# iPhone Simulator iCloud Photos Option Blank

Tags: ios, iphone, icloud, simulator, photos

I'm trying to enable iCloud Photos on the iPhone Simulator (Xcode 6.3.2, IOS SDK 8.3).
I have signed in and enabled iCloud and I can receive new calendar items via iCloud, but when I go to the Photos option under Settings/iCloud the page is blank and there are no options there.
Any one any ideas what's happening here.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No. I haven't had much time to get on with any iOS development at all. I've been doing .NET all the time.